# Mysqli_prepare not working

Tags: php

Solving this will allow me to solve another issue. Seems to me the statement isn't preparing or executing properly. I'm using a basic HTML form to debug and I know that the values are getting posted properly for username and password.

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
           if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    var_dump(mysqli_select_db($con,'db'));

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

     var_dump($username,$password);

    $statement = mysqli_stmt_prepare($con, "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    var_dump($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (strcmp($password,$colPassword)) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Here is the form if its of any interest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="LoginSecure.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>


<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the var_dump:

```
/home/r38w9q46ii75/public_html/LoginSecure.php:7:boolean true
/home/r38w9q46ii75/public_html/LoginSecure.php:12:string 'test2' (length=5)
/home/r38w9q46ii75/public_html/LoginSecure.php:12:string 'test2' (length=5)
/home/r38w9q46ii75/public_html/LoginSecure.php:14:null
{"success":false}
```

EDIT: CHANGES:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
           if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    var_dump(mysqli_select_db($con,'db'));

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

     var_dump($username,$password);

    $statement = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colPassword);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (strcmp($password,$colPassword)==0) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: you wanna `bind_result()` more vars (5) than the query returns (only 1). So the fetch will fail.

Comment: __AND__: Never store plain passwords in your db. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`!

Comment: and have a look at the docs for [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php). It does not work as you think! (and thus your if will give you 'wrong' result)

Comment: now it's time to check for errors! use [mysqli_stmt_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) to find out whats wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);
```

you wanna bind 5 vars to the result, but your query will only return one: 'password'.
As a consequence the fetch will fail and return false here `while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))`.

To solve that just remove the unneeded vars from your bind_result:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colPassword);
```

As an alternative you could of course also add the columns user, name, ... to your query.

*BUT* please don't store plain passwords in your database.
Use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)!

And third:
You have a locical error here:

```
    if (strcmp($password,$colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }
```

strcmp will return `0` if both strings are identical, but >0 if the first param is 'bigger' than the second one.
So `strcmp('test2', 'test')` will return 1 -> you will return `success=true`!
And vice versa, if the password is correct you will return success=false now.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. Some silly errors in there I'll admit, I went to bed at 5am haha, tough week. Still not working, I've added the changes to question. If you could still help out that would be great. Oh and I am of course going to hash the password, just for the sake of getting this script working I havent done for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need init and do a `SELECT * not only password`
Test this:

```
$statement = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);
```

Comment: I made the changes that Jeff suggested and added what you said. Still not working :(

Comment: No different to before :( I added the changes i made to the question

Comment: Try delete line with store_result

Comment: It's working, think I'm going made. Missed a single letter off the table name. Shocking.